# Bending arm Using armatures problem

Tags: armature, physics

[image]**I have this problem where it bend in the wrong face/place and I don't know how can I fix this .sigh. **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the mesh that you want to deform and go to the object data properties menu:

[image]

Then you can change the viewport mode to weigth paint in the upper left corner:

[image]

Now you can select the bone how misbehaves in the bottom right under the vertex groups
and paint over it a weight of 1 means that the movement of the bone Influences the mesh 100 % and a weight of 0 means that it doesn't influences it.

Comment: Thank you so much... It helps a lot, arigatou sensei !